# Fancybox Next/Previous buttons not showing up for simple content popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento, fancybox-2

I have a Magento 1.9.3.0 CE running site with custom News slider on Homepage.

In every news item in slider there is "Read More" link which opens the same news (a hidden div box containing same but full content of news) in full mode in a fancybox popup.

Now I have used below code for implementing that and also applied `rel="gallery"` in every "Read More" link.

```
$cnjQ('.news-owlgrid').children().find('a.cn-read-more').each(function() {
    $cnjQ(this).click(function() {
        var contentHref = $cnjQ(this).attr('href');
        $cnjQ.fancybox({
            /*'width': 750,
            'height': 750,*/
            'type': 'iframe',
            'content': $cnjQ(contentHref).show(),
            //'content': $cnjQ(contentHref).html(),
            'beforeLoad': function() {

            },
        });
    });
});
```

Then why still the Next Previous button doesn't show up in the popup which opens on clicking "Read More" link ?

Comment: Can you add link of working demo or code in snippet?

Comment: Well probably not, also jsfiddle site doesn't load properly here, but I am posting link here to my demo site homepage where I am getting the issue in the center news section, please take a look at it. http://115.112.143.25/ECO/mag/magento193/